# What is the purpose of adding scm information to a maven pom?

Tags: svn, maven

I understand why you would want to add archive information to a pom. But why SCM info? Is it possible to materialize a project completely from a pom?

The way I've always stored maven projects in svn, is I add everything (including the eclipse project, maven pom), to a repository. Any time I make a change to anything (including the pom), I do a SVN commit.

Is there a way to perform SVN operations directly through maven? Is this a best practice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [SCM plugin](http://maven.apache.org/scm/maven-scm-plugin/) among other features such as site generation use the SCM configuration in the POM.  The M2Eclipse plugin will [materialize your Maven project](http://www.sonatype.com/books/m2eclipse-book/reference/creating-sect-importing-projects.html#creating-sect-materializing-project) from SCM using the configuration found in the POM.

Comment: links dead, can you please elaborate in the answer itself, this answer is not sufficient for a newbie to understand.

Comment: @OptimusPrime - I am sorry that the answer was not helpful.  I haven't worked in this space in nearly 5 years!  I am glad you found a better answer from khmarbaise.

Comment: This answer is a copy paste from some random place

Comment: @Kronen It most certainly is not.

Answer (score 36):

Another thing is important to know about Maven in this relationship, because if you are doing releases via the [maven-release-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-release-plugin/) for which you need the SCM information, maven will automatically create SCM Tags for you etc.

Furthermore it's interesting to know where a project comes from if you are using an artifact in particularly in a commercial environment. (It's good to produce maven sites for that case).

It's also possible to do operations via the maven-release-plugin (create a branch) via Maven not via SVN directly.